# Should askers get access to edit tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-wiki

Get ready for some random rambling:

I am not a great answerer. There! I admitted it. I am either too slow or can't figure out the question.

But I do ask good questions, and I learn a lot from them. In the areas that I ask questions, I have become better (generally) at that subject matter.

As I use a tag more, I think, what does the wiki for this tag say? Almost always it is empty (no one has filled in anything).

Now, the experts who answer my questions are better suited to fill in this information. But they are (apparently) too busy answering questions (faster than me :)

So, me with my "decent" level of knowledge would like to fill it in. But I am not in the top 20 of the answers nor a bronze badge holder.

Is there a way to allow askers to have access to edit wikis? I am not sure what that should be, because some askers have a lot of questions but they are clearly hopeless on the subject matter. (Maybe upvoted questions?)

I don't even know if I think giving askers access to edit [tag wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-wiki/info) is a good idea. It has just been bouncing around in my head for a while, so I thought I would throw it out there.

Comment: I'm in favour. The tag wikis need more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will become a non-issue, anybody is going to be able to submit "edits" to tag wiki, and the the tag experts / mods will be able to approve or reject them.

Comment: Is that an up coming change?

Comment: yeah ... expect it in 6-8 weeks :)